# How to include only the functions from a php file?

Tags: php, function

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Including PHP functions from another file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050641/including-php-functions-from-another-file)

I'm building code that use function calls that exist in a thirdparty php file. This 3p php file is not a function library but also contain inline code itself.

How do I call the functions without executing the inline code?

edit: duplicate of [Including PHP functions from another file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050641/including-php-functions-from-another-file) ?

Comment: Good question, I never thought of it..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How do I call the functions without executing the inline code?

You can't.

You might be able to suppress the includes' output using [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php), but the code will still execute.

I don't think there is a good way to do this without making copies of the respective includes, and stripping the inline code from them.

Comment: You could `fsockopen` to localhost, etc.

Comment: @Steve-o huh? How will you get hold of the functions if you include the file externally? Please elaborate

Comment: I think I'm reading the question wrong, but thinking of calling the functions via HTTP such that the output is only within the socket.  But this implies the 3rd party API is `$_REQUEST` based.

Comment: @Steve-O my understanding of the question (@OP correct me if I'm wrong) is that he needs to import functions from a 3rd party library into his own application for later use, but without executing the inline code (= outside the functions) in the 3rd party include files. That won't work through http

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is you can't. A call to `include` is simply opening the file and running `eval()` on the content.

Answer (score 0):

How about splitting the original file into a functions-file and a native code file and including them? This way the original file will work as before and you would be able to include just the functions in your script.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically it is possible with evaling of filtered content of file, but filtering code is not an easy task in terms of scripting and performance.

Answer (score 0):

If all your functions are defined at the top of the file you want to include, you can add a structure like this to it immediately after the function definitions:

```
if (something that would be true if the file was included) {
  return;
}
```

For example, if the script doing the include has already defined a variable called `$myVar` you could do:

```
if (isset($myVar)) return;
```

This will cause the included file to stop executing and return control to your original script.

However, the best solution is to create another file called e.g. 'functions.php' and `include('functions.php');` in both scripts...